# how to include a jsp inside another jsp using <c:import>

Tags: spring, jsp, import, include

Hi Im new to Spring MVC and in my application I have several `.jsp` pages that have a nav-bar and a footer. So my questions are:

1. Can I put these elements(nav-bar, footer) in a single `.jsp` and then import that `.jsp` in my index, etc pages?
2. How can I do that without having to map the page that contains the nav-bar and the footer

PS: Im using Spring Security, idk if it matters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your `header.jsp` (navbar maybe) and `footer.jsp` or maybe a single `combinedheadfoot.jsp` and include these/this `jsp` in your other `jsp`'s by using:

`<jsp:include="header.jsp"/>`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad to know that it helped.

Comment: The only thing I have to add is that since my header.jsp, etc pages where in a different level than the index.jsp, I have to go with: <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/includes/header.jsp"/>   Just saying so if someone with the same problem sees this can solve it too.